# LAB: Count the digits. How did I do?

Tags: java, count, digits

Here is my code that I worked on and wondering how well did I do to simplify this? I just wanted to do my best to get a better understanding of Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   /* TODO: Write recursive digitCount() method here. */
   public static int digitCount(int userNum) {
    if (userNum == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + digitCount(userNum/10);
    
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num, digits;
      
      num = scnr.nextInt();
      digits = digitCount(num);
      System.out.println(digits);
   }
}
```

Comment: did it have to be recursive?

Comment: If your code is already working, and you are asking for feedback on possible improvements, then that is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow - but is likely a good fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You can take a look at their [how to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines, and get a feel for what types of questions are well received, before posting a question there.

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, your code does not work if input is `0`.
When `0` is passed, your function immediately returns `0` digits, which is wrong. Input number `0` consists of single digit and hence result should be `1`.

**Second**, you could optimize your recursive function using [tail-recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-recursion/).

```java
public static int digitCount(int userNum) {
    return digitCountRec(userNum, 0);
}

// Helper function performing tail recursion
private static int digitCountRec(int number, int digitCount) {
   if (number == 0) {
       return digitCount == 0 ? 1 : digitCount;
   }
   return digitCountRec(number / 10, digitCount + 1);
}
```